# Every power series expansion for an entire function converges everywhere

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to show that every power series expansion for an entire function converges everywhere.

Comment: This is Taylor's theorem.

Comment: What is your definition of an entire function?

Comment: More generally, a holomorphic $f:\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ has a power series expansion at any $z_0\in\Omega$ converging in the disk centered at $z_0$ with radius at least $\text{dist}(z_0, \mathbb{C}\setminus\Omega)$.

Answer (score 11):

Using [Cauchy's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) and integration by parts yields
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f^{(n)}(w)}{n!}\right|
&=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{f^{(n)}(w+z)}{n!\,z}\mathrm{d}z\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{f(w+z)}{z^{n+1}}\mathrm{d}z\right|\\
&\le\frac{1}{r^n}\max_{B(w,r)} |f|\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
where the integration is around the circle $z=r\,e^{it}$ for $t$ from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Estimate $(1)$, called [Cauchy's
 Estimates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_in_complex_analysis), says that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series for $f$ is at least $r$. Since $f$ is entire, we can set $r$ as large as we want.

Therefore, the Taylor series for $f$ at $w$ converges for all $z$.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe something is wrong with this answer, but it seems to be pretty simple.

First, we know that the power series of an analytic function is unique.  So if a function is entire (analytic in the whole complex plane), then its power series is unique on the whole plane, and by definition is convergent.

Comment: We know that the power series around any point is unique, but what does it mean to say "its power series is unique on the whole plane"?

Comment: Yeah, that was pretty sloppy, sorry.  I meant as you said: that the power series expansion of the function about some point in the plane is unique, and by entirety converges at every point in the complex plane.

Comment: If we're taking the definition of entire to be "all power series converge everywhere to the function" then your answer is a circular detour back to this definition.  Otherwise you're begging the question.