# A problem related to existence of entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exists a non-constant entire function  with the properties $f^n(0)=3^n$ for n is even and $f^n(0)=(n-1)!$ for n is odd ?

I have no idea,can i use coefficient formula of  power series(Taylor series) ?please someone help.Thanks.

Comment: What would be the radius of convergence of the Taylor series about $0$?

Comment: sir Is it 1/3 ?

Comment: Use the hint of @Daniel Fisher and please look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125201/every-power-series-expansion-for-an-entire-function-converges-everywhere

Comment: No, it's larger than that. The coefficients of the Taylor series are not $f^{(n)}(0)$, but …?

Comment: I doubt that you have no idea. For example, you know the root test. Report back when you try that test.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. If such function existed then its expansion at $z=0$ would be
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3^{2n}}{(2n)!}z^{2n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2n-1}}{2n-1}.
$$
Then, what would the radius of convergence be?